# Using Accord.Video.FFMPEG, I get "parameter is not valid exception". How can I solve it?

Tags: c#, winforms, video, ffmpeg

I want to extract all the frames from an [MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP4_file_format) video file and display them on a PictureBox.

The original code comes from this Q&A: *[How can I time the presentation and extraction of frames from a video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74157315/7444103)*

The exception happens after clicking the start button on the line:

```
var frame = videoReader.ReadVideoFrame();
```

#### The message

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileReader.DecodeVideoFrame(BitmapData bitmapData)
   at Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileReader.readVideoFrame(Int32 frameIndex, BitmapData output)
   at Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileReader.ReadVideoFrame()
   at Extract_Frames.Form1.<GetVideoFramesAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in D:\Csharp Projects\Extract Frames\Form1.cs:line 114
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Extract_Frames.Form1.<buttonStart_Click>d__17.MoveNext() in D:\Csharp Projects\Extract Frames\Form1.cs:line 151
```

#### The full code

```
using Accord.IO;
using Accord.Video;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract_Frames
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap frame = null;
        Graphics frameGraphics = null;
        bool isVideoRunning = false;
        IProgress<Bitmap> videoProgress = null;
        private CancellationTokenSource cts = null;
        private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
        private static long pause = 0;
        private int frameRate = 0;
        private List<Bitmap> frames = new List<Bitmap>();
        string fileName;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void StopPlayback(bool cancel)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (cancel) cts?.Cancel();
                cts?.Dispose();
                cts = null;
            }
        }

        int counter =1;
        private void Updater(Bitmap videoFrame)
        {
            frames.Add(videoFrame);

            label1.Text = "Current Frame Number : " + counter;
            trackBar1.Value = counter;
            counter++;

            //Size size = new Size(videoFrame.Width, videoFrame.Height);
            //pictureBox1.ClientSize = size;
            using (videoFrame) frameGraphics.DrawImage(videoFrame, Point.Empty);

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private async Task GetVideoFramesAsync(IProgress<Bitmap> updater, string fileName, int intervalMs, CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            using (var videoReader = new VideoFileReader())
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
                videoReader.Open(fileName);

                videoReader.ReadVideoFrame(1);
                trackBar1.Value = 1;

                label1.Text = "Current Frame Number : " + counter.ToString();

                while (true)
                {
                    if (Interlocked.Read(ref pause) == 0)
                    {
                        var frame = videoReader.ReadVideoFrame();

                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested || frame is null) break;
                        updater.Report(frame);
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(frameRate).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }

        private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frameRate = trackBar2.Value / 25;
        }

        private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = textBox1.Text;

            if (isVideoRunning) return;
            isVideoRunning = true;

            using (var videoReader = new VideoFileReader())
            {
                videoReader.Open(fileName);
                frame = new Bitmap(videoReader.Width + 2, videoReader.Height + 2);
                trackBar1.Maximum = (int)videoReader.FrameCount;
            }

            videoProgress = new Progress<Bitmap>((bitmap) => Updater(bitmap));
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            pictureBox1.Image = frame;
            try
            {
                frameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(frame);
                // Set the fame rate to 25 frames per second
                //int frameRate = 1000 / 25;
                await GetVideoFramesAsync(videoProgress, fileName, frameRate, cts.Token);
            }
            finally
            {
                frameGraphics?.Dispose();
                StopPlayback(false);
                isVideoRunning = false;
            }
        }

        private void buttonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pause == 0)
            {
                buttonPause.Text = "Resume";
                Interlocked.Increment(ref pause);
            }
            else
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref pause);
                buttonPause.Text = "Pause";
            }
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopPlayback(true);
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isVideoRunning) StopPlayback(true);
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = frames[trackBar1.Value];
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "video files (*.mp4)|*.mp4|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Get the path of specified file
                    textBox1.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to mention where you took the code from. I've added a link to the original Q&A -- Did you change those few pars of the code before or after you got the exception? Note that all operations are in a specific sequence for a reason -- Why did you add this: `videoReader.ReadVideoFrame(1);`? -- With what frame rate? -- You can't have this: private `List<Bitmap> frames = new List<Bitmap>();` and fill that collection, unless the video is very short. But you can use the reader to move to and read a specific Frame again (might be slow-ish, I know)

Comment: Would you like to use the frames to play the video inside the picture box or load them into a list and then switch as you display each inside the picture box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a library called Emgu CV to achieve this, but since Emgu CV uses a container called **Mat** to store the bitmap of an image, you will need to define a list of Mats and loop through the frames in the video and add them to the list. The first step is to install a NuGet package called **Emgu.Cv.runtime.windows** and then put the code below in the event handler that triggers the reading process.

```
// At the top of your Form1.cs file, import the Emgu CV library
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

// The code below goes to the button handler for reading the frames

// Declare the path to the video
string videoPath = "video.mp4";

// List to hold the frames read from the video
List<Mat> frames = new List<Mat>();

// Open the video with the Emgu CV video capture class
var video = new VideoCapture(videoPath);

// Useful line for reading the frame rate from the video
var frameRate = (int)new VideoCapture(videoPath).Get(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
while (video. Grab())
{
  // Read a frame and add to the list
  var mat = new Mat();
  video.Read(mat);

  // Add the frame to the list
  frames.Add(mat);
}

// Do something with the frames, for example access the
// frame at index 0 and display in the picture box
var first_mat = frames[0];
if(first_mat!=null){
   var outputFile = "1.png";
   // There isn't any direct way to get a bitmap from
   // a Mat, so save to a file and use the file as an
   // image location
   first_mat.Save(outputFile);
   pictureBox.ImageLocation = outputFile;
}
```

Comment: I have a question.  why in the original code when doing pictureBox1.Image = frame; it's adding to the pictureBox the frames each second or so and not 25 frames per second like in the video file ? ( I didn't install yet the Emgu CV I will install it now ).

Comment: You mean the code you posted that uses Accord.FFMPEG library?

Comment: You need to get the frame rate right. The frames need it to synchronize correctly.

Comment: right when I used the Accord.FFMPEG library.

Comment: You have to use a timer with an interval equal to the frame rate of the video which in your case is 25 to update the frames in the picture box.

Comment: It depends with the original objective for reading the frames into a list, did you want to play the frames using the picture box after loading them?

Comment: yeso ne of the feature I wanted is to play the frames in real time when they adding to the pictureBox.  like it does now but in the frame rate of the video.

Comment: Create a new timer with an interval that is equal to the frame rate of the video eg 30 milliseconds and then attach an event handler for the timer and put code that changes the frame inside the picture box using the frames in the list there.

Comment: I tried this changes with the timer but not sure if this test is realy 25 frames per second and how can I find the mp4 video file real frame rate by the code and then how to set it in the timer ? in general I want to control later with a trackBar on the frame rate. https://pastebin.com/qyEAbxkq the code is in the link.

Comment: You can use Emgu Cv to get the frame rate property of a video , updating my post to include how to read the frame rate of a video using Emgu Cv

Comment: @SheronBlumental, edited the question and added a line that let's you read the frame rate from the video programatically

Comment: tried to install the package and got this error:  Could not install package 'Emgu.runtime.windows.msvc.rt.arm64 19.33.31630'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: The latest version is incompatible with .net framework v4.8. Install  any version that starts with 4.4.x.x

Comment: working. is there a way to get the number of frames from the video file ? getting the frame rate is working but is there a way to get also the number of frames ? before starting the process. same like when getting the frame rate.

Comment: Would you like to get the total number of frames in the video file? It is equal to the count of the list where you were appending frames. This type `List<Mat> frames = new List<Mat>();`