# How to resolve a memory allocation problem in emgu cv?

Tags: c#, video, timer, emgucv

I am trying to create a simple video player application with Emgu CV and  Windows Forms. I have a picture box and a timer. The timer is for updating the frame on the picture box every 33 milliseconds. Then inside the Elapse event handler for the timer, I query a frame, convert it into a Bitmap and then I display it in the picture box. However the debugger shows this error when the first few frames of a video are read.

> The program '[5552] ProgramName.exe'has exited with code 3221226356

I researched the error a little and found out that it's a **Heap Corruption Error** which gave me a clue that I needed to work on how I manage memory for the video reading processes in my code.
I do not know if I need to dispose of the Mat object I use for querying the frames or I need to use inside a using block but this is how the code looks like.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
//timer for timing the frames
private Timer timer = new Timer(30);
//videocapture object for querying frames
private VideoCapture video;
//container for reading frames from the video
private Mat mat;
//integer to keep track of the current frame number
private int current Frame =0;
//integer to store the total number of frames in the video
private int frameCount = 0;

//subscribe to an event handler in the constructor of the form
 public Form1(){
 timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
 }

}
```

I have a menu strip item that when clicked opens the file browser for user to select a video file, here I instantiate video and start the timer.

```
private void loadVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
 //show an open file dialog
 var openfiledialog = new 
 OpenFileDialog();
 openfilediaog.Filter = "Video Files|*.mp4,*.avi";
 if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog()){
  //get the extension and ensure its a video file
   var ext = Path.GetExtension(openfiledialog.FileName);
   if(ext.Contains(".mp4") || ext.Contains(".avi")){
    //load the video 
    video = new VideoCapture(openfilediaog.FileName);
    //read the total number of frames
    frameCount = (int)video.Get(CapProp.Fps);
    //enable the timer
    timer.Enabled = true;
   }
 }

}
//this is the method that plays the video file
private void Timer_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){ 
  //instantiate mat
   mat = new Mat();
   while(currentFrame < frameCount ){
     //query a frame and display in the picture box
     mat  = video.QueryFrame();
     var bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>(true).ToJpegData()));
      pictureBox.Image = bmp;
      currentFrame +=1;
   }
 }
```

How do I efficiently manage memory in my code to get rid of this error

Comment: Dispose what is disposable of `mat`, `bmp`, `MemoryStream`, `ToImage`, `ToJpegData`, etc...

Comment: Not the MemoryStream. When you dispose the Bitmap, that also goes. The OpenFileDialog must be declared with an `using` statement  -- You shouldn't really do this: `Timer_Elapsed(...) {  [...] pictureBox.Image = bmp;  [...] } `, that event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread. Also, a `while` loop in an event handler? -- Take a look at: [How can I time the presentation and extraction of frames from a video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159167/7444103), try and follow that procedure. See also the comments (about the `PeriodicTimer`)

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks. I will visit te post and learn how to time the frames and display in the picture box

Comment: @aybe, you were right. It's about the memory. I used a using statement to define the mat and the video is playing fine .

Comment: Don't forget that you can use the diagnostics tools window to see memory usage in real time and perform profiling as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/running-profiling-tools-with-or-without-the-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: @aybe, I did and surprisingly it's the memory that's the root cause because the curve goes up then flattens then the program quits. It's a matter of reading the frames without letting them pile up

Comment: @Jimi, in your answer in the referenced post. You used Accord.Video to read frames from the video,  I am using a different library to do it, its an image processing library that is a wrapper to C++ open cv. Is there a way in which you can help me achieve a smooth playback using Emgu as the frame reading library?