# Error while trying to read an AVI file with stream.GetFrameOpen()

Tags: c#, avi

I am trying to use this package "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library". It is called "a simple c# wrapper for the avifile library"

I am trying to get an image from an avi file. This is the code from their website:

```
    AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(txtAviFileName.Text, true);
    VideoStream aviStream = aviManager.GetVideoStream();
    aviStream.GetFrameOpen();
```

But it always gets an error in `GetFrameOpen()` in VideoStream.cs which is called from the code just above. All it says is "Exception in VideoStreamGetFrameOpen!" without any details.

The weird thing is the supplied demo AVI (only 3 frames long) works but not with any of my AVI files.
Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Probably old stuff. If you have an AVI encoded with H.264, it won't find the codec. Use FFMPEG instead. Here is an example that uses Accord's FFMPEG video reader: [How can I time the presentation and extraction of frames from a video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159167/7444103)