# How to avoid from the custom progressbar to flickering?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a new usercontrol custom progressbar but when using it in the form1 designer by dragging the control over the form1 designer the progressbar flickering almost each second or less.

The progressbar i did it that the text inside the percentages will always stay in the center even when changing the control size. the problem is that it's flickering nonstop when using it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lightnings_Detector
{
    public partial class CustomProgressBar : UserControl
    {
        public CustomProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

            this.Height = 23;
        }

        private int _progressValue = 0;
        public int ProgressValue
        {
            get => _progressValue;
            set
            {
                _progressValue = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, value));
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private string _progressText = "";
        public string ProgressText
        {
            get => _progressText;
            set
            {
                _progressText = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle);
            var rect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, (int)(ClientRectangle.Width * ((double)ProgressValue / 100)), ClientRectangle.Height);
            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks(e.Graphics, rect);

            using (var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(ProgressText, Font, Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle, sf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue, no flickering at all. How are you using your user control in your form ?

Comment: it probably happens because you're drawing directly, try setting an image (or background image), and replace with new one each time (after you drew it)

Comment: Your Progressbar is in a `while` loop and it's repainted constantly, no matter the state of the video capture (also without checking whether the new values assigned are different than the previous ones) -- The `ProcessVideoFramesAsync()` method is not `async`, it just uses a couple of async methods, the other methods are synchronous. If there's nothing you can do about it, you should `Task.Run()` it and pass a `Progress<T>` delegate to update the UI, only when needed

Comment: How are you calling `ProcessVideoFramesAsync()` ?

Comment: Don't update progress bar (and other UI) the fastest possible, use some granularity instead.

Comment: I would suggest in a first time to comment everything except progress bar value incrementation to see if it is still flickering. Furthermore, you don't increment `processedFrames` inside your nested `while` loop

Comment: Does the same flickering occur when you use the standard `ProgressBar`?

Comment: @Jimi if i can't do about what? the method that is not async? can you show me example then how to change it? should I change it to a void and doing the whole process in a different way?

Comment: As mentioned, your `ProcessVideoFramesAsync()` method is not really asynchronous. You just have a couple of methods that are awaited in there, all the rest resumes in the UI Thread. The Progressbar is updated constantly no matter what. See the code here: [How can I time the presentation and extraction of frames from a video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159167/7444103) + the notes. It explains how this kind of procedure is done actually asynchronously -- If you instead decide to use `Task.Run()`, pass a Progress<T> delegate to the method. Do not use `Invoke()` to update the UI

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If you set this property to true, you should also set the AllPaintingInWmPaint to true.
> [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#fields)

So you should use the following line of code:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

Without *AllPaintingInWmPaint* your progress bar flickers when I resize it in the Designer. With *AllPaintingInWmPaint*, there is no more flicker during resize.