# extended file information without Shell

Tags: vb.net, shell, file

I am working with vb 2010.
I have a function that gives me the extended file information of video files via a shell function:
Example:

```
Dim folder As Shell32.Folder = Shell.NameSpace(fi.DirectoryName)
Dim fldItem As Shell32.FolderItem = folder.Items().Item(fi.Name)
Dim fldItem2 As Shell32.FolderItem2 = DirectCast(fldItem, Shell32.FolderItem2)
Dim Resolution = folder.GetDetailsOf(fldItem2, 316) & "x" & (folder.GetDetailsOf(fldItem2, 314))
```

This also works well.
I have now outsourced this function to a backround worker and get the error message that Shell32 is not usable.

How can I determine the extended file information without the shell function in a background worker?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You could use one of the .NET libraries that handle video sources, as, e.g., [Accord.Video.FFMPEG](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Video.FFMPEG/#readme-body-tab). You can read the frame size, frame-rate, number of frames etc., and, of course, [read any of the frames as a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159167/7444103), if you need to show a preview